how to config 'policy based routing' in ubuntu 22.04
I'm transitioning from Debian to Ubuntu. My network diagram shows a single server with two public WAN connections. I'm having trouble converting the routing policies.
Here are the current policies for Debian and the desired policies for Ubuntu. However, the Ubuntu policies aren't working as expected. Could you please assist me?
cat /etc/network/interfaces.d/eth0

# Primary WAN1 - VLAN 194   
allow-hotplug eth0.194
iface eth0.194 inet static
    address A.B.C.1
    netmask 255.255.255.248
    gateway A.B.C.2
    vlan_raw_device eth0
    post-up ip route add default via A.B.C.2 dev eth0.194 table wan1
    post-up ip rule add from A.B.C.1/32 table wan1
    post-up ip rule add to A.B.C.1/32 table wan1

# Secondary WAN2 - VLAN 195 
allow-hotplug eth0.195  
iface eth0.195 inet static  
    address X.Y.Z.1
    netmask 255.255.255.248
    gateway X.Y.Z.2
    vlan_raw_device eth0
    post-up ip route add default via X.Y.Z.2 dev eth0.195 table wan2
    post-up ip rule add from X.Y.Z.1/32 table wan2
    post-up ip rule add to X.Y.Z.1/32 table wan2


cat /etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml
# This is the network config written by 'subiquity'
network:
  ethernets:
    enp2s0:
      mtu: 9000
      addresses:
      - A.B.C.1/30
      - X.Y.Z.1/30
      nameservers:
        addresses:
        - 8.8.8.8
        search: []
      routes:
        - to: default
          via: A.B.C.2
          table: 201
        - to: default
          via: X.Y.Z.2
          table: 202
      routing-policy:
        - from: A.B.C.1
          table: 201
        - to: A.B.C.1
          table: 201
        - from: X.Y.Z.1
          table: 202
        - to: X.Y.Z.1
          table: 202

